# Make Windows ssh not use my Windows account by default?

Tags: windows-10, ssh

Seems like unless I specify `-l <account name on the remote computer>` when typing `ssh <ip>`, the ssh command just uses my Windows account name by default. This is annoying. Can I make it not use my Windows account name and ask for the user name by default, when `-l` is not used?

Answer (score 0):

OpenSSH always uses the current user's name unless you either specify one by writing it before an at sign (e.g., `ssh bk2204@example.com`) or you use the `-l` option.  However, you can adjust this using `~/.ssh/config` if you like by specifying something else:

```
Host github.com
    User git
Host *
    User bk2204
```

This will use the user `git` for `github.com` and `bk2204` for all other sites.  You can still override it at the command line with the two techniques I mentioned above.